# Do I have to use parenthesis in ruby function call before logical operator?

Tags: ruby

`''.instance_of?(String) && 0 == 0` is true, however

`''.instance_of? String && 0 == 0` gives
`TypeError: class or module required`

Do I have to use parenthesis before `&&`, or is it a bug?

Comment: Of course it is not a bug. Don't easily suspect a bug. Suspect your own thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug. The two things just mean different things.

The gist of it is that the `&&` and `||` logical operators have higher precedence than method invocation. So what happens is the `instance_of?` method is being called with the result of `String && 0 == 0`, which is `true`. `true` is not a class, hence the error.

On the other hand, `and` and `or` have lower precedence, therefore

```
''.instance_of? String and 0 == 0
```

would work the way you expected it to.

In this scenario, it is best to put the parenthesis.

Comment: Thx, so in general I should always use parenthesis before ops, right?

Comment: @dimid, if you wanted to call the method with the result of the logical operation - you didn't have to do it. However, the convention goes something like this - if you have no arguments, don't put them. If you have, omit them if the method has *"keyword-like status"*. In other cases - put the parenthesis in place.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug actually.
Though parentheses in Ruby method call are optional, when it becomes ambiguous, parentheses might be required.